# Trying to to Draw Tryptophan Using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Hello I am trying to draw as I stated tryptophan in a chemfig I tried this code but it does look like it any tips on how I can do it? I have been reading this document for [help](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf). [image: the diagram]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[grid,avery5371]{flashcards}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper} 
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{landscape} 
\newcommand{\cardrows}{5} 
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{2} 
\setlength{\cardheight}{3in} 
\setlength{\cardwidth}{3.5in} 
\setlength{\topoffset}{0.50in} 
\setlength{\oddoffset}{0.75in} 
\setlength{\evenoffset}{0.75in}
\geometry{headheight=10pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\small MCAT FlashCards Chemistry}

\begin{flashcard}[Amino Acids - NonPolarSideChains]
    {
        \chemfig{H_3N^+-C(-[2]H)(-[6]CH_2([6]*6(-\chembelow{=}NH=)))-C(=[1]O)(-[7]O^{-})}
    }
Name goes here
\end{flashcard}
\begin{flashcard}[Amino Acids - NonPolarSideChains Previous Attempt]
{
\chemfig{H_3N^+-C(-[2]H)(-[6]CH_2([6]*4(=NH=-)([6]*6(=-=-=-))))-C(=[1]O)(-[7]O^{-})}
}
Name goes here
\end{flashcard}
```

Comment: could you add a MWE of what you have tried so-far? just an uncompilable snippet is not really useful.

Comment: @Raaja I just have a list of the compounds on flash cards.  That small code at the bottom is my try.

Comment: @Raaja I inputted more code section but that was my attempt so far

Comment: That's completely ok, atleast make your script compilable in the form of a MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this (draw Tryptophan using `chemfig`) is to start from 6-ring.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{[:30]*6(-=-(-[:60]NH(-[:120]=[4]?(-[2]CH_2-[2]C(-[2]H)(-[0]C(=[1]O)(-[-1]O|{^-}))(-[4]H_3N{^+}))))=?-=)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in detail, how this answer helps the OP? could you make your script more explicit and compilable?

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\chemname{\chemfig{C_{\alpha}(-[5]H_3N^+) (-[7]C(=[1]O)(-[7]O^{-})) (>:[3]H) (<[1]C_{\beta}H_2(-[3]*5(-*6(-=-=-?)=-HN-=)))}}{Tryptophan, Trp, W}
```

[image]